# How to lock records in Oracle while doing some validation

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a `bash` script running a `Java` application every 5 min. The Java application gets records  from a table meeting certain conditions, from the `Oracle` database. 
I have to do several validations on each individual record returned in the `Resultset` and if the current record passes the validations,I add the particular record in an `ArrayList`.
And finally when all records are validated, do a batch update on these records.

The problem is that the validations take time and new records are added by that time.
So there are times when a previous script has not yet finished its execution, when a second script is running. What i want is to lock the current non-updated records so that another script does not fetch them from the database.

The best I can think of is having a status column in the table.

- status 0 - Not yet processed by the application
- status 1 - In process
- status 2 - Already processed

The Java application would fetch records where the status is 0, set them to 1 and perform the validations consequently. Finally after validations (success or not), the status is set to 2.

Can you think of a better alternative as it seems a bit "clunky".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the batch of records `FOR UPDATE`, which will lock only those rows and prevent another session from gaining a lock on them.

```
SELECT mycol
  FROM mytable
 WHERE ...
   FOR UPDATE
```

Comment: for update is the solution, ıf the process takes time other users will be waiting until the commit.

Comment: You can also think about coping the table and work on the copy.